# JavaFX - Array of Controls

Tags: java, arrays, oop, javafx, javafx-2

I want to create an Array of JavaFX controllers in order to be easier to work with them e.g. you could loop adding/setting elements in a GridPane.

But despite of the compiler/IDE not displaying any error this code below doesn't work:

```
public GridPane drawPane(){
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    Button[] btn = new Button[10];
    grid.add(btn[0], 0,0);
    return grid;
}
```

however this one **does work**:

```
public GridPane drawPane(){
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    Button btn = new Button();
    grid.add(btn, 0,0);
    return grid;
}
```

Am I instancing the controllers wrong? Why this code doesn't work with arrays ?

Comment: Where do you fill your arrays with Controls in the first example?

Comment: I tried it with a for loop, but I am trying to point out that even with a single instance of that array it doesn't works.

Comment: Of course your first example does not work. btn[0] is null. Initialize it properly and it will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this...
It will create an Array of Buttons and if you call your `getGrid()` Method it iterates through this Array of Buttons and adds them to the GridPane.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    private Button[] btns = new Button[10];

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        initBtnsArray();
        Group root = new Group();

        root.getChildren().add(getGrid());
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello Controller-Array-World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private Pane getGrid() {
        int i = 0;
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        for(Button b : btns) {
            // do something with your button
            // maybe add an EventListener or something
            gridPane.add(b, i*(i+(int)b.getWidth()), 0);
            i++;
        }
        return gridPane;
    }

    private void initBtnsArray() {
        for(int i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
            btns[i] = new Button("Button-"+i);
        }
    }
}
```

Patrick

Answer (score 5):

Your Array does not contain any Objects, so you will get a `NullPointerException`. Fill the array with an initialized Object to get it working.

```
public GridPane drawPane(){
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    Button[] btn = new Button[10];
    btn[0] = new Button(); //add this line
    grid.add(btn[0], 0,0);
    return grid;
}
```